# Counting Sequences: Find the Sum and Largest Entry

Tags: combinatorics

1. Let $S_1$ denote the sequence $(1,1)$.

For $n\ge 1$, we build a sequence $S_{n+1}$ by copying sequence $S_n$, inserting blanks between consecutive terms, and filling each blank with the sum of the two terms it's between. Thus we have
\begin{align*}
S_2 &= (1,\underline{2},1),\\
S_3 &= (1,\underline{3},2,\underline{3},1),\\
S_4 &= (1,\underline{4},3,\underline{5},2,\underline{5},3,\underline{4},1),
\end{align*}
and so on.

What is the sum of all entries in $S_7$?

2. Define the sequences $S_1,S_2,S_3,\ldots$ as in problem 1.

What is the largest entry in sequence $S_{11}$?

---

I don't see any way to count this constructively or a pattern.  Could someone please help me out?  Any answer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of sums goes $2,4,10,28,...$, and by inspection one can see that the sum is *probably* $3^{n-1}+1$. We seek to prove this by induction.

The base case is trivial, and the inductive step is left as an exercise to the reader (use the hint of Bolton Bailey).

Now onto the second question. The largest term in each sequence follows $1,2,3,5,8,...$, which suggests that it might be the $(n+1)$-th Fibonacci number (starting at $F_1=F_2=1$). We seek to prove this. Note that here, we want to prove that the largest number in $S_{n+1}$ is the largest number in $S_n$ plus the largest number in $S_{n-1}$, we are required to use strong induction.

Now, think about how we might prove this given how the sequence is defined. Where does it involve summing two terms that might be large?

Comment: Isn't it $(n+1)$-th Fibonacci number?

Comment: @YunaKun Yes - I just fixed it. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that the sequence $S_{n+1}$ contains a copy of every number of $S_n$, and that every number in $S_n$ other than the ones on either end is added into two other numbers in $S_{n+1}$.